# Counting sort in singly-linked list C#

Tags: c#, sorting, singly-linked-list, counting-sort

Is there any way to make a counting sort in singly-linked list? I haven't seen any examples and it's quite hard to make it without them. I have example of it in array and would like to do it in singly-linked list.
Has anybody did it in singly-linked list?

```
    public static int[] CountingSortArray(int[] array)
    {
        int[] aux = new int[array.Length];

        // find the smallest and the largest value
        int min = array[0];
        int max = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] < min) min = array[i];
            else if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
        }

        int[] counts = new int[max - min + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            counts[array[i] - min]++;
        }

        counts[0]--;
        for (int i = 1; i < counts.Length; i++)
        {
            counts[i] = counts[i] + counts[i - 1];
        }

        for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            aux[counts[array[i] - min]--] = array[i];
        }

        return aux;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found one that works on an array at:  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/

I think with minimal effort it could be changed to a linked list, the only problem is that you'll end up traversing the linked list many many times since you don't have random access eg.`[]` making it rather inefficient.  Since you seem to have found the same thing i did before I could finish typing I think my answer is kinda pointless.  However, I'm still a bit curious as to where you're having problems.

Heres a hint if figuring out where to start is the problem:  Every time you see `array[i]` used, you will need to traverse your linked list first instead to get the i'th item first.

Edit:  The only reason you would need to create a 2nd linked list of frequencies is if you needed to actually do work on the resulting linked list.  If you just need a sorted list of the values inside the linked list for display purposes an array holding the frequencies would work (i suppose at the same time you could just create an array of all the values then do the counting sort you already have on it).  I apologize if i have confused my c, c++, c++/cx, somewhere along the way (i don't have a compiler handy right now), but this should give you a good idea of how to do it.

```
public static node* FindMin(node* root){  //FindMax would be nearly identical
  node* minValue = root;
  while(node->Next){
    if(node->Value < minValue->Value)
      minValue = node;
  }
  return minValue;
}
public static node* CountingSortArray(node* linklist){
  node* root = linkedlist

  node* min = FindMin(linklist);
  node* max = FindMax(linklist);

  int[] counts = new int[max->Value - min->Value + 1];

  while(root != NULL){
    counts[root->Value] += 1;
    root = root->Next;
  }

   int i = 0;
   root = linkedlist;

   while(ptr != NULL){
     if(counts[i] == 0)
       ++i;
     else{
       root->Value = i;
       --count[i];
       root = root->Next;
     }
   }
}

void push(node** head, int new_data){
  node* newNode = new node();

  newNode->Value = new_data;
  newNode->Next = (*head);
  (*head) = newNode;
}

void printList(node* root){
  while(root != NULL){
    printf(%d ", root->Value);
    root = root->Next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void){
  node* myLinkedList = NULL;
  push(&head, 0);
  push(&head, 1);
  push(&head, 0);
  push(&head, 2);
  push(&head, 0);
  push(&head, 2);

  printList(myLinkedList);
  CountingSortArray(myLinkedList);
  printList(myLinkedList);
}
```

Comment: I'm having problems with thinking should I create a new LinkedList to store frequencies list and how to find min and max values in LinkedList, because this is what Counting sort is based around

Comment: As i'm sure you probably know, every node in a linked list has a 'value' and a pointer to the next node.  So implementing the 'find min and max' part of the code wouldn't be too hard.  the loop that is used would have to change.  I'd probably make a min and a max function that takes a node* and traverses the whole linked list once to find either min or max.  You wouldn't need a new linked list to store frequencies, you could actually use an array here, since u know the 2nd item in frequencies corresponds to the 2nd item in the linkedlist.  I'll write out some code for you in a few mins.

Comment: @Oilka somewhere along the way i just decided to make it sort the current linked list you give the sort algorithm instead of creating a new one or just returning the sorted values in an array.  Hope this helps (I also hope the code works lol)!

Answer (score 0):

The example code is more like a radix sort with base (max-min+1). Usually a counting sort looks like the code below. Make a pass over the list to get min and max. Make a second pass to generate the counts. Make a pass over the counts to generate a new array based on the counts (instead of copying data).  Example code fragment:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        counts[array[i]-min]++;
    size_t i = 0;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < counts.Length); j++){
        for(size_t n = counts[j]; n; n--){
            aux[i++] = j+min;
        }
    }
```